# Can't Git Push onto AWS EC2

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I've followed [this blog post](http://devoncmather.com/setting-aws-ec2-instance-lamp-git/#launchInstance) to set up a remote git repo on our AWS EC2 instance.

Eventhough I followed the blog post and set up my rsa public & private keys on my local machine and then added my public key to the remote aws ec2 server .ssh/authorised_keys I could not ssh with my RSA key.  I get the following error (I tried with both the public & private key).

```
$ ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_aws.pub ubuntu@5?.???.???.?4
Agent admitted failure to sign using the key.
Permission denied (publickey).
$ ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_aws ubuntu@5?.???.???.?4
Agent admitted failure to sign using the key.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I continued setting up Git as per the blog post in the hope that I could git clone, pull & push as I was abble to SSH with the AWS PEM key.

I was wrong and obviously git push requires an RSA key.

Now I get this error when I try a git push:

```
$ git push origin project-qa 
Agent admitted failure to sign using the key.
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
fatal: Unable to create '/var/git/project.git/refs/heads/project-qa.lock': Permission denied
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Any idea what I could be doing wrong?  I set the permisions on the remote AWS EC2 instance with:

```
chmod 640 .ssh/authorized_keys
chmod 750 .ssh
```

The .ssh/authorized_keys file looks something like:

```
ssh-rsa AAAA?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????xp qa-180615

ssh-rsa AAAAB????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????Gw== creed@creed-VirtualBox
```

Could it have something to do with the AWS Key Pair Name and the user name at the end of my ~/.ssh/id_rsa_aws.pub key?

Comment: it wouldn't have anything to do with the username at the end of the string. you need to ensure your pubkey in authorized_keys on the remote matches the pubkey for your id_rsa_aws. just to be safe you can run `ssh-keygen -y -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa_aws` to see if the pubkey there is actually the same as the one you are putting in the authorized_keys file. Just to be safe, remove the blank line from authorized_keys, too

Comment: @MikeD When I run `ssh-keygen -y -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa_aws` it's the same key but without `creed@creed-VirtualBox`.  Going to try removing it.

Comment: That wouldn't matter but ok. Make sure to remove the blank line from the remote's authorized_keys

Comment: @MikeD, tried that and removed the blank line but still getting the Permission Denied error :(

Comment: @MikeD, do you think it might have something to do with AWS security groups?

Comment: Seems like it would be basic ssh config. Make sure your private key perms are set right too. `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa_aws`. You could try adding `-v` as in http://serverfault.com/questions/39733/why-do-i-get-permission-denied-publickey-when-trying-to-ssh-from-local-ubunt